# Showing email in "Shipping Address"

Tags: magento2.3

How do I add so the customer can see which email they have entered in "Shipping Address" in the checkout?

Is it possible do it in the "Address Templates" (configuration->customers->customer configuration)? I have already tried {{var email}} without any luck.

[image: what i would like to achieve]

Hoping someone can help me with this.

Thanks in advance!
/Daniel

Answer (score 0):

I have been digging around and found out that the data that must be altered is in the shipping-address/address-renderer/default.html

But I cannot figure out how to get the customer email, I have tried with no luck address().email here is the code

```
<div class="shipping-address-item" css="'selected-item' : isSelected() , 'not-selected-item':!isSelected()">
<text args="address().prefix"/> <text args="address().firstname"/> <text args="address().middlename"/>
<text args="address().lastname"/> <text args="address().suffix"/><br/>
<text args="_.values(address().street).join(', ')"/><br/>
<text args="address().postcode"/>, <text args="address().city "/> <span text="address().region"></span><br/>
<text args="getCountryName(address().countryId)"/><br/>
<a if="address().telephone" attr="'href': 'tel:' + address().telephone" text="address().telephone"></a><br/>
<a if="address().email" attr="'href': 'mailto:' + address().email" text="address().email"></a><br/>
```

Is it not possible to add it somehow? I have searched and searched but i cannot find any information on this.